# What core configurations should be used in settings.php for a production site?

Tags: 8, configuration

Can someone please share Drupal core configurations that should be included and/or excluded from settings.php to make the site both performant and secure?

Comment: Absolutely up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal 8 has a default settings.php you can use:

```
sites/default/default.settings.php
```

Just copy it as `sites/default/settings.php`, add your DB connection array - and you are pretty much ready to go. Then use the UI to turn on caching and CSS/JS aggregation.

For security you may want to add in your Trusted Host Pattern

```
# TRUSTED HOST PROD
$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = [
  'mysite\.com$',
];
```

If you really want to you can lock down your caching & preprocessing settings in the settings.php file, rather than setting it through the UI

```
# CACHING & JS/CSS AGGREGATION PROD
$config['system.performance']['css']['preprocess'] = 1;
$config['system.performance']['css']['gzip'] = 1;
$config['system.performance']['js']['preprocess'] = 1;
$config['system.performance']['js']['gzip'] = 1;
$config['system.performance']['cache']['page']['max_age'] = 86400;
```